# Button Image does not refresh instantly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want my App to play music the first time the play Button is played, after that it should swap the Button Image to pause. It doesn't refresh instantly but only after the Song is being played already and I press the play Button again 2 times.

[image]

[image]

```
    @State var isPlaying: Bool = false
    @StateObject var musicPlayerVM: MusicPlayerViewModel
    @StateObject var audioManager = AudioManager()

Button() {
                    if isPlaying == false {
                        audioManager.startPlayer(track: musicPlayerVM.song.track)
                        isPlaying = true
                    } else {
                        audioManager.playPause()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: audioManager.isPlaying ? "pause" : "play.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 19, height: 25)
                }
```

````
final class AudioManager: ObservableObject {
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    @Published private(set) var isPlaying: Bool = false
    
    func startPlayer(track: String) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: track, withExtension: "mp3") else {return}
        
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player?.play()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to initialize player: ", error)
        }
    }
    
    func playPause() {
        guard let player = player else {
            print("Instance of audio player not found")
            return
        }
        if player.isPlaying {
            player.pause()
            isPlaying = false
        } else {
            player.play()
            isPlaying = true
        }
    }    
}
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `isPlaying` to `true` inside of your `AudioManager` class when you first start the player.

```
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player?.play()
        isPlaying = true  // here
    } catch {
        print("Failed to initialize player: ", error)
    }
```

Your `isPlaying` in your view has a different purpose than tracking pause status, so I suggest you give it a different name such as `playerStarted` to avoid confusion.

A better idea is to use an `enum` to give your `AudioManager` 3 states: `.stopped`, `.playing`, and `.paused` and use it as the single source of truth.

Comment: The bottom code snippet would start playing the track from new on again and not playing from where it was paused

Comment: Oh, I see now.  I suggest you use a different name then like `playerStarted` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Also, you’re going to want to set your `AudioManager` as a delegate of the player so that it knows when the song is done. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioplayerdelegate#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioPlayerDelegate/audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully